# Should I hide upload file information after user have uploaded 1 or more files

Tags: verification, uploading, upload

I have some information that I show in my upload form:
 - The limit of file size
 - Available file formats to upload

Should I hide this information after user have uploaded 1 or more files?
Images attached

File(s) not uploaded:
[image]

File(s) uploaded:
[image]

Comment: You could make it a bit shorter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I would advice against removing critical information from the screen.**

From the screenshots you've provided, I don't see any way of bringing back the information about the file size. Just because the user already performed a valid action, doesn't mean there isn't a chance of them forgetting the instructions or making a mistake.

The problem will become more pronounced if the user tries to upload in bulk. Just imagine having to show 20 errors for wrong file size and the effort the user would have go through to correct the mistake.

Just like you don't remove the, *"Drag here or browse to upload files"* instruction, keep the instruction about the file sizes, format, etc. also available on the screen. You can, however, choose to minimize it even though it isn't the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the objective of the user in mind. While the immediate goal of the user here looks like uploading some documents, it is not the actual objective. The actual objective is something else. In order to achieve his or her real objective, a user will not try to remember all the smaller details on the page even if these were performed earlier, worse so if these uploads were carried out a day or earlier. What if the user is trying to resume his application process after a week and he or she does not have any information about the file size or format required.